# Did Minato give BEE his nickname?

Tags: naruto

Has been stated officially that it was Minato who gave BEE the title of shinobi killer? I seem to want to think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Minato did in fact call [Bee](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Killer_B) a “Shinobi Killer” in *Naruto Chapter 543*. This occurred during Minato’s battle with B and the 4th Raikage.

> The two from this encounter Minato would come to have much respect for B and his abilities. Minato even stated that B acted as a true shinobi killer, thus giving him the title of "Killer"

[image: Minato calling Bee a killer]